# How to fix display of Count in MpAndroidchart

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore, mpandroidchart

I'm having a bit of trouble since when I get a count from my firestore database, it displays 25 instead of 1. I can't seem to solve this problem. I think it shows 1/4 of the count, since when I tried to add only three counts the output displays only 33.33.

Here is my code, I have searched for ways to fix this but I don't seem to find ways to fix it.

```
private void setPieChart() {
    pieChart.setDrawHoleEnabled(true);
    pieChart.setUsePercentValues(true);
    pieChart.setEntryLabelTextSize(12);
    pieChart.setEntryLabelColor(Color.BLACK);
    pieChart.setCenterTextSize(24);
    pieChart.getDescription().setEnabled(false);

    Legend l = pieChart.getLegend();
    l.setVerticalAlignment(Legend.LegendVerticalAlignment.TOP);
    l.setHorizontalAlignment(Legend.LegendHorizontalAlignment.RIGHT);
    l.setOrientation(Legend.LegendOrientation.VERTICAL);
    l.setDrawInside(false);
    l.setEnabled(true);
}
private void loadPiechartData() {
    entries = new ArrayList<>();
    db.collection("charot")
            .whereEqualTo("electricity", "lugi")
            .count()
            .get(AggregateSource.SERVER).addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
                entries.add(new PieEntry(task.getResult().getCount(), "lugi"));

                db.collection("charot")
                        .whereEqualTo("mahal", "bawi")
                        .count()
                        .get(AggregateSource.SERVER).addOnCompleteListener(task2 -> {
                            entries.add(new PieEntry(task2.getResult().getCount(), "bawi"));

                            db.collection("charot")
                                    .whereEqualTo("basta", "ewan")
                                    .count()
                                    .get(AggregateSource.SERVER).addOnCompleteListener(task3 -> {
                                    entries.add(newPieEntry(task2.getResult().getCount(),"ewan"));
                                        db.collection("charot")
                                                .whereEqualTo("tuiton", "pwede")
                                                .count()
                                    .get(AggregateSource.SERVER).addOnCompleteListener(task4-> {
                                 entries.add(new PieEntry(task4.getResult().getCount(), "pwede"));
                                                    if (task.isComplete()) {
                                                    ArrayList<Integer> colors = new ArrayList<>();
                                  for (int color : ColorTemplate.MATERIAL_COLORS) {
                                                            colors.add(color); }
                                  for (int color : ColorTemplate.VORDIPLOM_COLORS) {
                                                     colors.add(color); }
                                  PieDataSet dataSet = new PieDataSet(entries, "");
                                  dataSet.setColors(colors);
                                  PieData data = new PieData(dataSet);
                                  data.setValueFormatter(new ValueFormatter() {
                                  @Override
                                  public String getFormattedValue(float value) {
                                  return String.valueOf((int) value)}
                                  });
                                 data.setDrawValues(true);
                                 data.setValueTextSize(12f);
                                 data.setValueTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                                 pieChart.setData(data);
                                 pieChart.invalidate();
                                 pieChart.animateY(1000, Easing.EaseInOutQuad);
                                                    }
                                                });
                                    });
                        });
            });
```

I'm still getting the hang of Charts and even my group couldn't fix it.

This is my database
[image]

and this is the output

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `pieChart.setUsePercentValues(true);` in `setPieChart()`, so it is showing percentages instead of the actual values. Remove that or set it to false if you want to see values.

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line

> pieChart.setUsePercentValues(true);

You can also use the Tasks class instead of nesting queries.